Power analysis for zero inflated poisson / negative binomial
I would like to perform some power analysis to help plan experiments.
Specifically, the experiment aims to test if a treatment reduces the number of plant pathogens. The experimental setup is different sites, and each site contains both "treatment" and "control" quadrants.
From previous experiments, I know that my response variable (number of pathogens) can be modelled using a negative binomial and/or a zero-inflated Poisson distribution.
I have two questions, one practical and one theoretical:

I have found some academic papers on power analysis for zero-inflated Poisson distributions, but I could not find an R package that would implement these. Any pointer appreciated for that!
In my experiment, the pathogen can be absent, hence the ZIP distribution. However, as field work is costly in resources (money/time), I would like to be able to tell if a site is worth sampling or not. Obviously, if there is no pathogen, the site is not informative. My understanding is that a low pathogen pressure (nb of pathogens) is "less informative" than a high pathogen pressure. Is it possible to define a threshold of pathogen pressure, or would that definitely violate a statistically sound sampling scheme? If not, how would that relate to the power analysis?

Thank you in advance for any pointer!

First point: if the paper you are referring to is the Lin, Lyles, and Williamson (2006) paper, if there's not an R package, you can still do it by hand. I have done it by hand many times, they lay out all the steps in the paper. It shouldn't be more than 50-100 lines of R code. There might be an R package, but I couldn't find one in a 2 minute search.
Second: Agree that if there are no pathogens at site (presumably pre-treatment), it's a waste of time to survey it. You can split your study into different pathogen levels as you wish; how you do it will have implications on how your can interpret your data. For example, say the pathogen count ranges between 0 and 500. If you only survey about 150, then you can't draw inference about sub-150 counts without making some assumptions. I advise thinking through the options, and balance out the money and statistical costs to find the best way forward. Keep the ultimate outcome/use-case of your analysis in mind when doing this.
